# How do you use css media queries in choo.js?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

in case someone was wondering

you install sheetify in your project

with npm

`npm install sheetify`

then within your choo component

```
const html = require('choo/html')
const css = require('sheetify')

const yourVariable = css`
  :host {
    color: red;
  }

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    :host {
      color: blue;
    }
  }

`
const yourComponent = () => {
 return html`
         <h1 class=${yourVariable}>This text is styled</h1>
 `
}
module.exports = yourComponent
```

Comment: the question is in the title and the answer is in the content. yeah. it's a questions with ONE answer so far ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can also export the whole css as a js module and use `app.use('./path/to/module')`

say you need to style your `html` or `body` tags

example :
in `app/assets/cssStyles.js`

```
const css = require('sheetify')

module.exports = function () {
 return css`
     html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
  }
`
}
```

then in your root file `app/index.js`

```
....
const styles = require('./assets/styles')

app.use(styles)
.....
```